# Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'click.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\Components\Click.js'

Tags: reactjs

Please I am facing a big error in my new react.js app

Module not found: Error:

```
 Cannot find file: 'click.js' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\Components\Click.js'.
```

This is the Click.Js files

```
import React from "react";
    
    export class Click extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
        
          this.state = {
             count: 0
          }
        }

        UpdateClick = () => {
            this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 })
        }
      render() {
            const { count } = this.state;
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.UpdateClick}> This is the button details , however i have been clicked {count} times</button>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    export default Click
```

I've tried this https://web-brackets.com/discussion/6/-solved-cannot-find-file-index-js-does-not-match-the-corresponding-name-on-disk-react-js

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the component at the top

`import {Component} from "react";`

or

`import React, {Component} from "react";`

Comment: Thank you. I just tried that now.... still same error

Comment: I checked your code and it worked fine.
I think one of your module files is damaged or not loaded correctly.
You can rebuild the project with vite (https://vitejs.dev/) and make sure the modules are loaded correctly.